# Better way to make sure all members of an object array have an equal count

Tags: php, oop, if-statement, methods

I'm trying to figure out a better way to figure out if four members of an object array posses the same count, I have this code in my method, but it seems like this should be able to be pushed off to its own protected method instead. I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but I just can't think of a better way? The way that I have my switch set up now just seems clunky and a waste of code

```
if (count($this->optional->foo) === count($this->optional->bar) 
=== count($this->optional->baz) === count($this->optional->qux)
) {
    /** continue **/
}
```

Comment: This question makes no sense and your abstraction is leaking.

Comment: Sure it makes sense, I'm looking for a better way to make sure that all four members have the same count. I believe that repetitively doing `count ===` is a waste. And honestly, all non-trivial abstractions, to some degree are leaky.

Comment: Wrong. All abstractions that use public class variables are leaking. That does not make them "non-trivial". It's simply lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a shot...

Optional Class:

```
public function areAllEqual( )
{

    return count( $this->foo ) === count( $this->bar ) === count( $this->baz ) === count( $this->qux );

}
```

Comment: You should always use `===` for comparing (in both PHP and JS).

Comment: I avoid blanket statements such as 'always'. It may be recommended in most circumstances, but always is not accurate. Updated my post anyway.

Comment: Well .. yes. I lost my train of thought there. I wanted to add *"(..) unless you expect values to be typecast"*, but by the time I looked up if your profile contains "javascript" tag, I had forgot to add it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = array(count($foo), count($bar), count($baz));
return (count(array_unique($test)) == 1);
```

(This allows you to test more properties simply by adding them to the `$test` array.) If you change $this->optional->foo (etc) to $this->optional['foo'], you can easily use array methods and save this step.

Comment: You might want to read [`array_unique()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/standard/array.c#2811) source. It's not as good of idea as you might expect.

Comment: This would/should work since `$this->optional->(object_name)` IS and object array.

Comment: duh... I shortened it to $this->foo, $this->bar in my test code. `foreach ($this->optional as $opt) { $test[] = count($opt);}`